# How do I save the table information to localStorage?

Tags: jquery, html-table, storage

Here's the problem I am "creating" new tables with jQuery but when I refresh it obviously goes away. So I of course go to localStorage. For some reason I am having trouble with it though. I need to not only save the information in the tables to localStorage but the info is also editable so whenever it gets edited that needs to be saved also. How should I go about this? Here is the code. If you need more info or have questions I'll answer quick.(important code is in while loop)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.button1').click(function() {
        $('.inventory').html("");
    });

    $('.addItem').click(function() {
        while (true) {
            let partNum = prompt("What is the part number?");
            let quantity = prompt("What is the quantity of this part?");
            let description = prompt("Describe this part(optional)");
            $("table").find('tbody').append( `<tr><td contenteditable='true'>${partNum}</td><td contenteditable='true'>${quantity}</td><td contenteditable='true'>${description}</td></tr>` );
            break;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Nothing in your code relates to local storage. If you'd like us to help you debug saving to local storage, there has to be something for us to debug!

Comment: I tried to use localStorage but it wasn't working. I'm asking to see how I would use it. (I'm not very familiar with it)